# Could not detect supported target files in 'project directory'see documentation supported languages target, make sure you are in the right directory

Tags: monitor, snyk

I am new to Snyk and I have installed `synk-cli` and ran the command `snyk monitor` on the root directory of my project which contains two apps,
client == reactJS, server== python(Django), I have authenticated my VS code to connect to my Snyk account but I got this error

```
Could not detect supported target files in /Users/yusuf/projects/ project_name.
Please see our documentation for supported languages and target files: https://snyk.co/udVgQ and make sure you are in the right directory.
```

I have looked at the official documentation and it says you might get this error by either the language is not supported or I am in the wrong directory, however I have check both, as I mentioned I am running node(react) and python(django) and both are supported by Snyk and I am definitely in the correct directory, also I have cd to server to run only on language at a time (in this case will be user/yusuf/projects/project_name/server) but still get the same error above

Answer (score 2):

I have some information that might help.

1. The `CLI` looks for the manifest in the current directory. Its default behavior is to find a manifest and perform a scan for open source scanning using `snyk test`.
2. You can have Snyk look for multiple manifests in a mono repo using `--all-projects`
3. The first step to identify the issue is to determine the `package.json`, `pipy`, `pip-env` files in that root. Not only is it in the root but is a supported manifest? If it's not in the root we can always point to those files.

The second step is to either run it with `--all-projects` or to target each one with a `snyk test --file=..` and you will likely have to specify the package manager. The docs indicate to do this

```
--file=<FILE>
Specify a package file.
When testing locally or monitoring a project, you can specify the file that Snyk should inspect for package information. When the file is not specified, Snyk tries to detect the appropriate file for your project.

--package-manager=<PACKAGE_MANAGER_NAME>
Specify the name of the package manager when the filename specified with the 
 --file=<FILE> option is not standard. This allows Snyk to find the file.
Example:$ snyk test --file=req.txt --package-manager=pip
```

The commands are mentioned here: commands: https://docs.snyk.io/snyk-cli/commands/test